# console.dir(this) not producing any output

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I have this:

```
<body>
<script>
console.log(this);
console.dir(this);
console.dirxml(this);
</script>
</body>
```

Why does console.dir(this) not produce any output?

Comment: It produces the exact same for me in Google Chrome's Developer Tools as `console.log`. Please be more specific :)

Comment: I'm using Firefox with Firebug.

Comment: Edited tags. This info should have been in there from the start. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should show the console object as it would in the DOM panel. But it will pay attention to your settings. Go to the DOM tab panel and click the triangle menu thing and be sure it is showing user properties and user functions. Then try again.